# One single HTML5 audio download stalled on Chrome but good on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I've put up a bunch of audio downloads with SoundManager2 + PXLoader, but one of the audio files cannot be properly downloaded in Chrome. Last update, it was my 'Tempest III.mp3' file. Now Chrome is picking on 'Op 111 I.mp3'. Also, for whatever reason, it seems that once an audio file is stalled, a bunch of image files will be hit too, and stop downloading. I have to reload a few times to get the images in the cache so they will be loaded before the offending audio file. It works in Firefox and IE11. Why is Chrome doing this to my files?

The project is here:
http://www.newgrounds.com/projects/games/778014/preview

The audio appears as 'stalled' in the console. Thanks in advance!

ETA: It also works fine locally.

Edit: I tried reducing the number of audio files by one, and Chrome still failed to download one of the audio files.

Comment: Try reducing the number of audio files you're loading to 6 or less.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. Is there a file size/no. of files limit of which I'm unaware?

Comment: It's fine with five files. Will try six in a moment.

Comment: For whatever reason, it stalls with six files, but only images are stalled. If anyone knows a solution, I'll be really happy, but I think I'll have to add loading bars for each scene for now. (Yikes - more work! Though on the plus side, I'll get to add more adverts, mwahahaha!)

Comment: Yeah, I believe there is a limited number of concurrent connections to the same domain. For Chrome that number is 6 and I believe Firefox is limited to 8 by default. A possible solution is to host the audio on different sub domains.

Comment: Thanks, idbehold! No wonder why it worked on Firefox - I had exactly eight files. Well, that's a headache... I guess I'll put up loading bars for each scene *and* have the app destruct() the audio file of the previous scene to allow for more connections...

Comment: You should check out [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that one. It should be easy to extend PXLoader to support howler.js, but I have one question - does howler.js close the connection after downloading the audio file fully, and somehow allow the audio to 'stand-by'? If not, I don't think the problem would be solved...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57797/discussion-between-flyingcolours-and-idbehold).